# Linked button in extjs

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I want to create link button in EXTjs .. and it should open new window onclick 
I am using html code

```
     xtype: 'component',
       autoEl: {
          tag: 'a',
          html:  'Rearrange Column',
          href: <a href="http://kanishkkunal.in"  target="popup"  
onclick="window.open('http://kanishkkunal.in','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;"> 
Open Link in Popup
</a>,

           }
```

I am referring this http://www.marcusschiesser.de/2009/01/14/3-ways-to-render-html-inside-of-a-extjs-container/

[https://superdevresources.com/open-links-popup/e](https://superdevresources.com/open-links-popup/)

I want to modify href code so that it will work in extjs without error ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign click event to component and write your code there

```
  {
     xtype: 'component',              
     html:  'Rearrange Column',
     autoEl: {
        tag: 'a', 
        href:'#' 
     },
     listeners: {
        el: {
            click: function(){
               window.open('http://kanishkkunal.in','popup','width=600,height=600');
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: it is working but I want to create link button .. it is just coming as a text ..user should know it is link button ..so How to create link button

Comment: Just add this:  autoEl: {   tag: 'a',  href: '#'  }